# What are the non-degenerate faces of $N\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: category-theory, classifying-spaces

I don't understand the nerve construction. For $\mathbb{Z}_2$, Wikipedia says $\bullet \overset{1}\longrightarrow \bullet \overset{1}\longrightarrow \bullet$ should produce a nondegenerate 2-simplex, but I don't see how if there's only one vertex/object and two edges/arrows - by face maps or inspection, the edge $\bullet \overset{1}\longrightarrow \bullet$ is repeated. Some edge must be repeated in any 2-simplex, so all 2-simplices should be degenerate.

So the problem in particular is the geometric realization of two loops on a point is a figure 8, which should be the classifying space of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, doesn't have fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_2$. And that's stretching it, because the edges are degenerate, so if it's a true complex it should just be a point, with trivial fundamental group.

Comment: The nerve of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has simplices in all dimensions; its geometric realization is (homotopy equivalent to) $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$. Why are you only looking in up to $2$ dimensions?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've been trying to see some non-trivial 2D structure before looking at the rest. Won't n-simplices still all be degenerate if there are no non-degenerate (n-1)-simplices?

Comment: Your definition of degenerate simplex is incorrect: the nerve is a simplicial set, not a simplicial complex. A degenerate simplex is a simplex that is the image of a degeneracy operator, and just because it has repeated faces doesn't mean it's degenerate!

Comment: @ZhenLin Ahhh! Simplicial sets, thank you, and I can take that as an answer. That makes much more sense for what it should be doing. In the sense of a degenerate polytope, my definition is correct, but I know I'll be glad to know "degenerate simplex" is typically used to mean the image of a degeneracy map whenever those are defined.

Comment: Followup: I didn't recognize Qiaochu's comment that the nerve was $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$, only recognizing the cross-cap in construction, but I didn't know how to go about seeing that. After constructing $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as the antipodal gluing of the unit sphere, and $\mathbb{RP}^3$ as the unit ball with an antipodal gluing of its surface, it's clear how to demonstrate this fact.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I didn't want to give the personal answer at the time, because I thought it would be off-topic, but I think it's relevant to education. I took the 2-skeleton because I had trouble understanding how the shape followed from syntax, and when you could look at some relationships and say they followed the syntax of nerves. I had families of objects with relations, and I suspected these were nervelike, so I constructed one to find out what that meant (how it could be proved). I couldn't grasp the syntax as a whole yet, so I couldn't predict what would happen at all dimensions.